# How to see the code in debagging state in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

I might not formulate the question correctly, so I'll use pictures to better explain it.

When I use breaking points in debugging I see only numbers:
[image]

Thought what I should see is the code itself, like on screenshot below:
[image]

What should I change in preferences in order to get the same view?
I tried to use different searching options but no-one raises that question. It's like all have this by default.

Comment: You might have a setting turned on that shows you the location in memory. Try searching for settings related to `memory locations`, `memory addresses` or `view memory`.

Comment: Please include code, not images of code, which can’t be searched, copied and pasted, or read by screen readers.

Comment: @jnpdx The question isn't about specific code. It's asking how to get the debugger to show source code instead of assembly code.

Comment: @AlexiusdeVinco thank you! Using your reference found it in:
Debug - debug workflow - Always show disassembly (uncheck it)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that I was of some help! Would you mind accepting my answer that I just posted? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings in Xcode and find: Debug > debug workflow > Always show disassembly (uncheck it).

*Note: The Disassembly window shows assembly code corresponding to the instructions created by the compiler.*